# Agrupar dados em uma tabela php

Tags: php, html

Minha necessidade é agrupar as notas ficais em uma única linha onde as OE são repetidas por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código abaixo:

```
<?php 

foreach($class->Lista($empresa,$fatura) as $dados) { 

    $CdFatura = $dados->getFatura();
    $NrNFSe = $dados->getNrNFSe();
    $CdOE = $dados->getCdOe();
    $NrNotaFiscal = $dados->getNrNotafiscal();

    echo '
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NrNFSe</th>
                    <th>OE</th>
                    <th>NotaFiscal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$NrNFSe.'</td>
                    <td>'.$CdOE.'</td>
                    <td>'.$NrNotaFiscal.'</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    ';
}

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com o código abaixo:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;

foreach($class->Lista($empresa,$fatura) as $dados) { 

    $i++;

    $CdOE[0] = 0;

    $CdFatura[$i] = $dados->getFatura();
    $NrNFSe[$i] = $dados->getNrNFSe();
    $CdOE[$i] = $dados->getCdOe();
    $NrNotaFiscal[$i] = $dados->getNrNotafiscal();

    if($CdOE[$i] != $CdOE[$i-1]){
        ?>

        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>OE</th>
                        <th>NotaFiscal</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $CdOE[$i]; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                                foreach($class->ListaNF($empresa,$CdOE[$i]) as $dados) { 
                                    echo $dados->getNrNotaFiscal().'<br>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez a abordagem abaixo funcione, mas para isso é necessário que a lista esteja ordenada pelo "**CdOE**" (como aparenta no seu exemplo), pois assim os indexes com mesmo código vão estar sempre um após o outro.

```
        $lista = $class->Lista($empresa, $fatura);

        // executa enquanto a lista tiver valor
        while (!empty($lista)) { 
            // pega o valor atual do ponteiro
            $dados = current($lista);
            // remove este valor da lista
            unset($lista[key($lista)]);

            $CdFatura = $dados->getFatura();
            $NrNFSe = $dados->getNrNFSe();
            $CdOE = $dados->getCdOe();
            $NrNotaFiscal = $dados->getNrNotafiscal();

            // pega o atual index da lista (o anterior já foi removido)
            $nextDados = current($lista);

            // executa este laço enquanto o próximo código existir e
            // for igual ao código atual
            while ($nextDados && $nextDados->getCdOe() == $CdOE) {                
                $NrNotaFiscal .= "<br>{$nextDados->getNrNotafiscal()}";

                // remove o index usado e pega o pŕoximo
                unset($lista[key($lista)]);
                $nextDados = current($lista);
            };

            echo '
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NrNFSe</th>
                            <th>OE</th>
                            <th>NotaFiscal</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$NrNFSe.'</td>
                            <td>'.$CdOE.'</td>
                            <td>'.$NrNotaFiscal.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            ';
        }
```

Obviamente, não consegui testar exatamente com o seu código, mas pela lógica deve funcionar. Antes de executar é bom analisar a estrutura do seu array e tomar alguns cuidados para que não caia em um loop infinito durante os testes (o que pode travar a máquina).
Para isso, você pode utilizar um contador interno dentro do laço como segurança.

```
$i = 0;
while (!empty($lista) && $i < 100) { 
    $i++;
```

Faça isso no outro laço interno também.

Comment: Deu certo porém deu este erro `Call to a member function getCdOe() on boolean in` no `while ($nextDados->getCdOe() == $CdOE) {`

Comment: @Kevin.F provavelmente em algum momento o valor do "$dados" está vindo como null, neste caso acredito que validando o elemento antes de chamar a function deve resolver.

Atualizei a resposta com uma validação a mais no segundo while.

Comment: Entendi, só que agora as notas que que vem cada OE são as mesmas numerações porém vem a quantidade certa. Por exemplo na OE 36 está vindo 4 vezes a nota  1127437.

Comment: Isso acontece porque estava chamando as 4 vezes a mesma variável principal ($dados), ao invés da nova variável ($nestDados). Problema corrigido.